# how to replace empty cells in gtsummary tables with NA

Tags: regression, gtsummary

The journal styling requires all empty cells to be marked for NA

This attempt shows no change:

```
library(gtsummary)

glm(response ~ age + stage, trial, family = binomial) %>% 
  tbl_regression( exponentiate = TRUE) %>% 
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>%
      mutate(
        across(all_stat_cols(), ~gsub("^0.*", "NA", .))
      )
  )
```

NOTE: using `everything` instead of `all_stat_cols()` gives me this error:

> Error in `map()`:
> ℹ In index: 1.
> Caused by error in `mutate()`:
> ℹ In argument: `~gsub("^0.*", "NA", .)`.
> Caused by error:
> ! `~gsub("^0.*", "NA", .)` must be a vector, not a  object.

Answer (score 1):

I figured we can do this using `modify_table_styling` function

```
glm(response ~ age + stage, trial, family = binomial) %>% 
  tbl_regression( exponentiate = TRUE) %>% 
   modify_table_styling(
    columns = everything(),
    rows = !is.na(variable),
    missing_symbol = "NA"
  )
```